# How Can I extract data in python with the same value of fields using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization

I Have a dataset with fields id, time, date, name, etc. I want to extract data that has the same id and date. How can I do that?

For example

```
id    time    date
1    16:00    03/05/2020
2    16:00    03/05/2020
1    17:00    03/05/2020
1    16:00    04/05/2020
2    16:00    04/05/2020
```

Now I want to fetch :

```
1    16:00    03/05/2020
1    17:00    03/05/2020
```

Answer (score 1):

Can `groupby` and `filter`

```
df.groupby(['id', 'date']).filter(lambda s: len(s) > 1)
```

---

```
    id  time    date
0   1   16:00   03/05/2020
2   1   17:00   03/05/2020
```

Comment: now how I just print that data  and plot time with some other parameter ?

Comment: That's a different question. Please don't use one question for (potentially many) follow-ups. Try some stuff and, in case you have more doubts, post a new question